# Update of resource type is not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to update ElasticSearch cluster to OpenSearch using cloud formation template but I get this error **Update of resource type is not permitted. The new template modifies resource type of the following resources: [ResourceName]**. I don't want to delete the existing domain because it contains important information.

I was following this article but unsuccessful: https://onecloudplease.com/blog/migrating-to-opensearch-with-cloudformation

Comment: What is your current template and what exactly do you want to change?